I want to setup a validator/RCP node in Turkey, need snapshots closer to Turkey
I got a server in Turkey, which matches the server requirements mentioned in https://docs.solanalabs.com/operations/requirements ,  with a 1GBit outbound.
I setup the solana-validator with those params
#!/bin/bash
# set -e
# set -u
#export RUST_LOG=error

ulimit -n 1000000

solana-validator \
        --identity validator-keypair.json \
        --known-validator 7Np41oeYqPefeNQEHSv1UDhYrehxin3NStELsSKCT4K2 \
        --known-validator GdnSyH3YtwcxFvQrVVJMm1JhTS4QVX7MFsX56uJLUfiZ \
        --known-validator DE1bawNcRJB9rVm3buyMVfr8mBEoyyu73NBovf2oXJsJ \
        --known-validator CakcnaRDHka2gXyfbEd2d3xsvkJkqsLw2akB3zsN1D2S \
        --expected-genesis-hash 5eykt4UsFv8P8NJdTREpY1vzqKqZKvdpKuc147dw2N9d \
        --entrypoint entrypoint.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
        --entrypoint entrypoint2.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
        --entrypoint entrypoint3.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
        --minimal-snapshot-download-speed 500000 \
        --rpc-port 8899 \
        --wal-recovery-mode skip_any_corrupted_record \
        --init-complete-file data/init-completed \
        --limit-ledger-size  \
        --only-known-rpc \
        --full-rpc-api \
        --no-voting \
        --enable-rpc-transaction-history \
        --enable-cpi-and-log-storage

When I ran the script, it tries to get the snapshots. and those snapshots are mostly coming from USA or Japan.
ie: (this is from US) http://145.40.64.255:8899/snapshot-290968999-CVvhRru9Kds5TU3QumZRyWzJtawTDfzfiChyD47QqoLy.tar.zst
Unforunately, the network connections to those are very slow from Turkey. Its downloading like ~3MB/s which is causing our server to not catching up the transactions.
Is there a way to setup my validator, which can get the snapshots and gossips closer to Turkey?
Which parameters should I change?
My solana version is
$ solana --version
solana-cli 1.18.18 (src:83047136; feat:4215500110, client:SolanaLabs)


It looks like you're setting a pretty low --minimal-snapshot-download-speed of 500 kb/s, where the default is 10 MB/s. Have you tried removing that flag or setting it to something higher than the default of 10485760?

it worked, but I apperantly need to change the location from Turkey to Sweden
thanks
